# How to run properly chmod in OSX with C#?

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, mono, chmod

I have the same problem as here [How run chmod in OSX with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505353/how-run-chmod-in-osx-with-c-sharp)

I would like to change permission via code in Unity
I tried :

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() 
{
    FileName = "chmod",
    Arguments = "+x " + "Game.app/Contents/MacOS/Game"                              
};

Process proc = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, };
proc.Start();
```

but doesn't work, any advices?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! could you specify `doesn't work` a little further? Any exceptions/errors? Does anything happen at all? Do you pass the correct arguments/path?

Comment: no errors but not work, I tried the same commands via terminal and everything works

Comment: are you sure your code is called/executed at all? (breakpoints & debugging)

Comment: yeah, I'm sure. Maybe I added the wrong arguments?

Comment: maybe the path isn't correct? I don't know how the relative paths work for Unity on iOS. Maybe you will have to specifiy the `startInfo.WorkingDirectory`

Comment: I testing standalone mac build not iOS, testing different paths right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but maybe you first have to open e.g. `bash` and then pass in the `chmod` call as parameter using `-c` something like

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() 
{
    FileName = "/bin/bash",
    Arguments = "-c \" chmod +x  Game.app/Contents/MacOS/Game\" ",

    CreateNoWindow = true
};

Process proc = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, };
proc.Start();
```

still assuming ofcourse the path is correct.

and maybe also add some callbacks like

```
proc.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(e.Data);
};
proc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(e.Data);
};
proc.Exited += (sender, e) =>
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(e.ToString());
};

proc.Start();
```

Comment: still the same result,

Comment: I see result (ExitCode) 1 in Exited Delegate

Comment: ok so atleast we know the command is executed and for some reason fails (exit code 1) maybe first you should try to run `"-c \"ls Game.app/Contents/MacOS/Game\""` and see if maybe the according file is not found

Comment: ah, sec. I see the problem. my game has space in the name (Test Game.app) everything works great when I removed space

Comment: I replaced name Test\" Game and works. thanks a lot for your time